# How to reload a library in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

*library is calling from 2 functions. when I call it second time it pick the data of first function. I want to reload the library in second function.

```
public function impnewsdetail($ref) {
    $url = array(
       'base' => $ref,
       'category' => ""
    );

    $this->load->library('crawler', $url);
    $nd = $this->crawler->getNewsDetail();
    $newsdetail = array(
      'detail_heading' => $nd['detail_heading'],
      'detail_tags' => $nd['detail_tags'],
      'detail_date' => $nd['detail_date'],
      'detail_image' => $nd['detail_image'],
      'detail_image_detail' => $nd['detail_image_detail'],
      'detail_text' => $nd['detail_text']
    );

    return $newsdetail;
}
```

Comment: your question is lacking information. Please tell where is the second function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this I am not sure..

```
$this->load->library('crawler');
$mylib= new Mylib($url);
$mylib->somemethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

If You don't wish to set different library names (as @mic suggests), You can **unset the library** to force the Loader to load again with another config:

```
$this->load->library ('crawler', $url_1);
unset ($this->crawler);
$this->load->library ('crawler', $url_2);
```

Comment: upvoted because your answer is more performatic than @mic answer

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could set a unique name for the object you are loading. This can be done like this:

```
function method1()
{
    $this->load->library('crawler', $url, 'crawler1');

    $this->crawler1->method();
}

function method2()
{
    $this->load->library('crawler', $url, 'crawler2');

    $this->crawler2->method();
}
```

Now each instance of it will be unique.

I hope this helps, Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will find this question, here is my solution:
you can define new method in your library with will change your library' option:

Example - In your library define:

```
function __construct($initParams = array())
        {
           //..somecode
           // init option here 
           //........
           // end init
        }
//add this function to re-config:
function reloadConfig($initParams){
           //simple re-call init option code
           // init option here 
           //........
           // end init
        }
```

In Use:

```
$this->load->library ('crawler', $option1);

//and when want to change option:
$this->crawler->reloadConfig($option2);
```